# why isn't Spring MVC finding the path to my views?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring and I'm trying to make a simple web app, however I cannot get started with the basics and cant make even a HelloWorld application.

Here is what I am Using:

Spring 5
Spring boot 2.1
Eclipse Photon, I used the add-on Spring Tools Version 3.9.6 to create the proyect

Here is what I did:
Created via File -> New -> Spring Starter Proyect, selected type package type as WAR, also in the dependencies section I selected Web

Added jstl and jasper dependencies to the pom.xml, here is the whole file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.logback.app</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-logback</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-logback</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    **<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>           
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>            
    </dependency>**
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My view template is as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Logback</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<h2><c:out value="${titulo}"/></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("titulo", "Pruebas Logback");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And I added these to the application.properties file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF-/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: jsp
```

With all these configuration it should work, but when I enter the address localhost:8080/index it throws what it looks like a 404 error

[image]

And the strangest thing is that neither in the web browser console or in the Eclipse console are errors that point out to the right direction.

What do you think it can be?
Thanks ind advance

Comment: Is your controller in the same package as your spring boot application?

Comment: Are you sure that the path `WEB-INF-/views/index.jsp` is correct? Shouldn't it be `WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`?

Comment: I feel so silly now! That was it, the path was incorrect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Piotr Podraza I realized my mistake

Changed

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF-/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: jsp
```

to

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

The path to my views was incorrect, and I was missing the period of the jsp suffix

Thank you!